# Modify HTML Element

Tags: html, css, vba, excel, internet-explorer-11

I don't know the proper jargon, but is there a way to modify an HTML element using VBA? Consider the following example:

```
<span class="display">HH</span>
```

Is there a way to change the value "HH" to something else via VBA? I've been working on this for several hours now, and my lack of HTML knowledge is severely limiting my progress... my latest attempts involved trying to set attributes of the element, but I realized I was going about the issue the wrong way. So now I'm at a loss.

I'm trying to change the value of a drop down list (in SurveyMonkey), but the drop down isn't like other drop down lists I've seen.
[image]
[image]

The code for the drop down lists is as follows:

```
<span class="timepicker btn-menu">
    <a href="#" class='btn btn-small hour-menu-btn btn-menu-left select-menu'>
        <span class='display'></span><span class="arrow smf-icon">–</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-small minute-menu-btn btn-menu-right select-menu">
        <span class='display'></span><span class="arrow smf-icon">–</span>
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-small ampm-menu-btn btn-menu-right select-menu">
        <span class='display'></span><span class="arrow smf-icon">–</span>
    </a>
</span>
```

I used to use this code to change the hour setting:

```
objIE.Document.getElementById("ddlHour").selectedIndex = 6
```

But now there's no ID, and I get `Run time error 438: object doesn't support this property or method` when I try `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`. Any help is much appreciated!

---

**Edit**

Both lines below raise the following error: "Object variable or With block variable not set"

```
d.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-small hour-menu-btn btn-menu-left select-menu").item(1) = 6
d.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-small hour-menu-btn btn-menu-left select-menu").item("display") = 6
```

"d" is the HTML document (and it is set). I also tried adding `.selectedIndex = 6` to the end, but got the same error.

The following error is raised if I use the below line of code: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

```
d.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-small hour-menu-btn btn-menu-left select-menu").item(0) = 6
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: getelementbyid returns a single node, because IDs must be unique in the DOM. getelementsbyclassname returns a nodelist/array, because there may be multiple nodes matching. generally speaking, you'd need `getElementsByClassname('div')[i]` to access the actual i'th element in the list.

Comment: @MarcB Please see my edit. I tried your suggestion with no luck.

Comment: get rid of the `.item(#)` part of your statement. Does it work with simply `d.getElementsByClassName($class_name)(1)`?  And ensure `MsgBox d.getElementsByClassName($class_name) is Nothing` returns False.

Comment: @DavidZemens The `MsgBox` does indeed return False. I still get Run time error 91 when I drop the `.item(#)`. But I don't really know which property to use to try to change the value of the drop down... should I still be attempting `.selectedIndex`, or should I be using something else?